# Dust js How to check whether the condition is true at least once in a loop

Tags: javascript, templating, dust.js

Here is my data that has to be rendered:

```
var data = {
    "foo" : "1",
    "project": [
        {
            "name": "Project 1",
            "status": "red"
        },
        {
            "name": "Project 2",
            "status": "green"
        },
        {
            "name": "Project 3",
            "status": "red"
        }
    ]
};
```

I want to loop through this data and print projects with status red, yellow, and green separately. If there is no project of particular status type then I want to display `no yellow/red/green project`. I am able to display the projects under their particular status but how do I find whether there is no project of the current status type.

My dust template is:

```
<h1>red</h1>
{#project}{@eq key=status value="red"}{name}
{/eq}{/project}
<h2>green</h2>
{#project}{@eq key=status value="green"}{name}
{/eq}{/project}
<h2>Yellow</h2>
{#project}{@eq key=status value="yellow"}{name}
{/eq}{/project}
```

Please see: http://jsfiddle.net/xuLSq/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not absolutely sure, but DustJS doesn't support this use case.

Since it's a templating engine, I guess they encourage you to expose plain data in your model and avoid such kind of logic in the template itself.

You might split your model as follows:

- redProjects
- greenProjects
- yellowProjects

And then you won't require DustJS syntax to get this working!

Comment: Even my research suggests the same. I found one temporary hack using jquery http://jsfiddle.net/xuLSq/1/ but I guess splitting the model is the best solution. Thanks :)

Comment: @AbhasTandon Hey, no problem :) I've checked your workaround, but it's a bad decision, because DustJS rendering happens before the whole template is added to the DOM, so it seems that splitting the model is the friction-free solution!

Comment: Yes, I have decided to split the model into three parts as suggested. I understand that jQuery solution is just a temporary fix and not a good way doing it. Thanks again...